# Analytic complex function with $u=v^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I must prove that if $f = u+iv$ is analytic with $v=u^2$ then $f$ is constant. My attempt is $$f(x,y) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y) = u(x,y)+iu(x,y)^2$$ and write $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial }{\partial y} (u(x,y)^2) = 2u(x,y) \cdot u_y$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u(x,y)^2) = 2u(x,y) \cdot u_x$$ f is analytic so we can use the Cauchy - Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} = 2u(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$  $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2u(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ so $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -4u(x,y)^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \implies v(x,y) = -\frac{1}{4}$$ is that right? I feel like I'm missing a lot of things. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: no, the last step is wrong. What happens if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=0$? I suggest you rearrange the equation and look carefully at which factor is non-zero and divide accordingly

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: Actually, both $u_x=-4u^2u_x$ and $u_y=-4u^2u_y$, so for any point $(a,b)$, either $u(a,b)=-1/4$ or, if not, then both $u_x(a,b)=u_y(a,b)=0$. So, if $u(a,b)\ne1/4$, then $u(x,y)$ is constant in some neighborhood of $(a,b)$.

Answer (score -1):

The image of the holomorphic f lies on the parabola u=$v^2$ and hence the image omits more than one point in the complex plane. Thus the function is a constant by Picard’s theorem.

Comment: Of course,I presume that the function is defined on the entire complex plane and is entire. Otherwise it is not true.

Comment: In think the result is true in any domain in the complex plane. It is not necessary to assume that $f$ is analytic in the whole plane.

Comment: Picard is super overkill. I can think of at least two other arguments that start with the observation that the image lies on a parabola and ends with $f$ constant, but neither uses Picard. First, you could follow the suggestion in the comments, get that $f$ is constant near a point, and use the identity theorem. Second, you could observe that the image is not open, contradicting the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Actually, I can't use Picards' theorem yet. I'm taking my first class on complex analysis and we didn't see it for now. But i appreciate the comment! I will try the two sugested arguments.